# Testing functional component in React onChange

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test a functional component. And the goal is to evaluate that the value change correctly.

I have only managed to carry out the test checking that it renders. But I can't find a way to pass the props to him

InputPassword

```
export default function InputPassword({ password, SetPassword }: any) {
  return (
    <input
      type="password"
      placeholder="password"
      value={password ?? ''}
      onChange={(event) => SetPassword(event.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

Test:

```
test('Login InputPassword', () => {
  render(<InputPassword />);
  const username_input = screen.queryByPlaceholderText(/password/i);
});
```

Update final code

```
test('Login InputPassword', async () => {
  const fakePass = '123';
  const fakeCb = jest.fn();
  render(<InputPassword password={fakePass} SetPassword={fakeCb} />);
  const usernameInput = screen.queryByPlaceholderText(/password/i);
  expect(usernameInput).toHaveValue(fakePass);
  fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: '000' } });
  expect(fakeCb).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Exactly the same way you always pass props to a component in JSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `render` function you can pass props to the component just like you would pass props anywhere else.

```
test('Login InputPassword', () => {
  render(<InputPassword password="123" />);
  const username_input = screen.queryByPlaceholderText(/password/i);
});
```

Based on your comment:

```
test("Login InputPassword", async () => {
  const fakePass = "123";
  const fakeCb = jest.fn();
  render(<InputPassword password={fakePass} setPassword={fakeCb} />);
  const usernameInput = screen.queryByPlaceholderText(/password/i);
  expect(usernameInput).toHaveValue(fakePass);
  await userEvent.type(username_input, "changed");
  expect(usernameInput).toHaveValue("changed");
  expect(fakeCb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(7);
});
```

On mount the input displays the password that is given to it via props. Then after the user provides a new password which calls the handler accordingly and the input's value is also updated.

Comment: And about the useState hook how to simulate the change inside ?
  const [password, SetPassword] = useState();

Comment: If you type anything in the `username_input` textbox using `userEvent`/'fireEvent` the click handler will be called inside the test and then state update would happen.

Comment: @Cazs I've updated my answer please have a look! Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah is just it!! thanks matter